# How can I update/revert a feature which includes page manager and mini panel components that is stuck as overriden?

Tags: 7, panels, features

I have a feature which includes page manager and mini panel components that is stuck as overriden?

I have tried reverting and updating the feature both from the web ui and also from drush to no effect.  I don't get any error messages but after clearing the cache twice the feature is still marked as overriden.

Generating a diff reveals about twelve differences that look like this:
+'new-6' => array(
-'new-1' => array(
+'pid' => 'new-6',
-'pid' => 'new-1',

I assume this is the result of the site on which I created the feature having a lot more content already in place than the site on which I have installed the feature, which has no other content.

I also tried removing the offending parts (those related to page manager and panels) from the feature, updating the feature, and then adding them back onto the feature using the web ui, but it still displays as overriden.

I found this thread but there wasn't any particularly helpful information:
http://drupal.org/node/744450

Any ideas about how I can update or revert this feature?

Comment: Three years from then, still remains for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Attempting to answer the question:**

You should be able to simply re-export the feature to update the pane identifiers in code.

**Background info:**

There are two parts to this problem.
First of all, features uses a different way of determining whether or not something is overridden, than ctools does. So Ctools consider the state to be "in code", but features, "overridden".

Secondly, the way panes are identified have recently changed. The change initially came about to solve a particular bug, but now causes other problems instead, namely the 'new-X' "overrides".

There are several different patches in the Panels queue that all have different ideas on how this problem should be solved. Currently, I'm afraid to say that I believe you can't do a great deal about this. The current behavior simply isn't optimal.

You can read more in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1369246), and the ones that are linked to.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What exactly do you mean by "simply re-export the feature"?  I tried using "drush features-update myfeature" and then cleared the cache but it still shows as overriden.  Then I tried re-creating the feature in the UI, overwriting the files, and clearing the cache-- still no luck.    I could edit the code directly I suppose but if this is going to happen a lot I strongly prefer a different solution.

Comment: Re-creating through the UI was what I meant. Sometimes, I don't think features updates the export unless you de-select your component and re-selects it. Did you try that? I've added an issue queue link to the answer.

Comment: Thank you!  As per your advice, I tried de-selecting and re-selecting and several other things but I couldn't remove the "overridden" status.  However, reading the issue queue I realized that this is simply falsely reporting that the feature is overriden when it is not; since it doesn't appear to affect the site, I will just ignore it for now.